# What are the differences between .reverse() and [::-1]? Python list .reverse() works but [::-1] does not

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a problem from leetcode. I think lots of you are probably familiar with.

```py
class Solution:
    def rotate(self, matrix: List[List[int]]) -> None:
    """
    Do not return anything, modify matrix in-place instead.
    """
    matrix.reverse()
    n=len(matrix)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i):
            matrix[i][j],matrix[j][i]=matrix[j][i],matrix[i][j]
```

With the code above, if input is [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]].
Then, the output is [[7,4,1],[8,5,2],[9,6,3]] which is expected.

But, if I use matrix{::-1]:

```py
class Solution:
    def rotate(self, matrix: List[List[int]]) -> None:
    """
    Do not return anything, modify matrix in-place instead.
    """
    matrix=matrix[::-1]
    n=len(matrix)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i):
            matrix[i][j],matrix[j][i]=matrix[j][i],matrix[i][j]
```

If I just change .reverse() to [::-1], the output is [[9,6,3],[8,5,2],[7,4,1]].

I don't understand why am I getting these different results. Other than .reverse() being inplace, [::-1] create a new list, is there any other different between them? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Since `matrix.reverse()` is in-place, the passed list is modified. `matrix=matrix[::-1]` creates a new list local to the function, so the passed list stays intact (and the docstring lies).

Comment: Your second `rotate` method does not reverse the list passed in; it creates a new list with the reversed contents of the original.

Comment: `matrix[:] = matrix[::-1]` would fix the problem.  This creates a new reversed list, but then replaces the entire original list with the new list.  It's about 3.5x slower than `matrix.reverse()`, however (tested with IPython %%timeit).

Comment: @MarkTolonen Understandably, as it needs to reallocate and copy memory

Comment: Alternatively, adding a return statement may solve the issue.